# UIImagePickerController fullscreen

Tags: iphone, camera, picker

i'm using the UIImagePickerController to show the camera view in my main view, calling it with this code:

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

and i have a self made toolbar in my storyboard, to manage some camera's functionality. 
What happens is that when the app loads, the camera seems to overlay my toolbar, going in fullscreen and hiding my buttons. Why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal the [`UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) is ment to run full screen. You can an extra overlay view to the [`cameraOverlayView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-SW19) property to show you own controls.

Comment: May i ask you an example of this implementation? i cant find one on the web! if i did understand well it is like a view (designed in the storyboard?) shown over the camera, how do i declare and initialize it?

Thanks in advance